# How to make Selenium only click a button and nothing else? Inconsistent clicking

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My goal: to scrape the amount of projects done by a user on khan academy.

To do so I need to parse the profile user page. But I need to click on `show more` to see all the project a user had done and then scrape them.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException,StaleElementReferenceException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# here is one example of a user
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/trekcelt/projects')

# to infinite click on show more button until there is none
while True:
    try:
        showmore_project=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'showMore_17tx5ln')))
        showmore_project.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        break
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        break

# parsing the profile
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')

# get a list of all the projects
project=soup.find_all(class_='title_1usue9n')

# get the number of projects
print(len(project))
```

This code return `0` for `print(len(project))`. And that's not normal because when you manually check `https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/trekcelt/projects` you can see there that the amount of projects is definetly not `0`.

The weird thing: at first, you can see (with the webdriver) that this code is working fine and then selenium clicks on something else than the `show more button`, it click on one of the project's link for example and thus change the page and that's why we get `0`.

I don't understand how to correct my code so selenium is only clicking on the right button and nothing else.

Comment: when I run your code, it returns 381.

Comment: Try showmore=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'showMore_17tx5ln')))
        showmore[0].click()

Comment: Also, try waiting until the whole page is rendered after clicking, and the use BeautifulSoup to get the html code.

Comment: @mm_ I get this error mesasge `showmore_project[0].click()
TypeError: 'WebElement' object does not support indexing`

Comment: @mm_ My problem is not the rendering time, but the clicking function, when I run my code it is clicking on show more button and then it clicks on a different link, thus beautiful soup is not parsing the page I wanted.

Comment: @_RobZ Can replicate that behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following implementation to get the desired behavior. When the script is running, take a closer look at the scroll bar to see the progress.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    driver.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/trekcelt/projects')

    while True:
        try:
            showmore = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[class^="showMore"] > a')))
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",showmore)
        except Exception:
            break

    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
    project = soup.find_all(class_='title_1usue9n')
    print(len(project))
```

Another way would be:

```
while True:
    try:
        showmore = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[class^="showMore"] > a')))
        showmore.location_once_scrolled_into_view
        showmore.click()
        wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[class^="spinnerContainer"] > img[class^="loadingSpinner"]')))
    except Exception:
        break
```

Output at this moment:

```
381
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. Now though can we have a way to make that script faster? it takes aproximatly 30 secondes to do it. The thing is I have many profiles like this one. How can we improve this script to make it run faster?

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the accepted answer to improve the performance of your script. Comment on how you can achieve it is in the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
start_time = time.time()
# here is one example of a user
with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    driver.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/trekcelt/projects')
    # This code will wait until the first Show More is displayed (After page loaded)
    showmore_project = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,
                                                                                       'showMore_17tx5ln')))
    showmore_project.click()
    # to infinite click on show more button until there is none
    while True:
        try:
            # We will retrieve and click until we do not find the element
            # NoSuchElementException will be raised when we reach the button. This will save the wait time of 10 sec
            showmore_project= driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.showMore_17tx5ln [role="button"]')
            # Using a JS to send the click will avoid Selenium to through an exception where the click would not be
            # performed on the right element.
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", showmore_project)
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            continue
        except NoSuchElementException:
            break

    # parsing the profile
    soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')

# get a list of all the projects
project=soup.find_all(class_='title_1usue9n')

# get the number of projects
print(len(project))
print(time.time() - start_time)
```

Execution Time1: 14.343502759933472
Execution Time2: 13.955228090286255
Hope this help you!